# Call non static method in PageRenderer Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I have a simple code that make authentication in Platform-specific code:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(FacebookLoginPage), typeof(FacebookLoginRenderer))]
namespace VejoSeriesMobile.Droid.Renderers
{
    public class FacebookLoginRenderer : PageRenderer
    {
        public static string ClientId = "";
        public static string ClientSecret = "";
        public static string Scope = "email, public_profile";
        public static string AuthorizeUrl = "https://m.facebook.com/dialog/oauth";
        public static string RedirectUrl = "https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html";
        public static string AccessTokenUrl = "https://m.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/token";
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Page> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            var activity = this.Context as Activity;
            var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator(
              clientId: "717427648360004",
              scope: Scope,
              authorizeUrl: new Uri("https://m.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/"),
              redirectUrl: new Uri("http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html"));
            auth.Completed += OnAuthenticationCompleted;
            activity.StartActivity(auth.GetUI(activity));
        }

        async void OnAuthenticationCompleted(object sender, AuthenticatorCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                var request = new OAuth2Request("GET", new Uri("https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id,name,picture,email"), null, e.Account);
                await request.GetResponseAsync().ContinueWith(t =>
                {
                    var fbUser = JObject.Parse(t.Result.GetResponseText());
                    var id = fbUser["id"].ToString().Replace("\"", "");
                    var name = fbUser["name"].ToString().Replace("\"", "");
                    var email = fbUser["email"].ToString().Replace("\"", "");
                    var conta = new Account { Username = name };
                    conta.Properties.Add("email", email);
                    AccountStore.Create(Context).Save(conta, "VejoSeries");
                    App.SuccessfulLoginAction.Invoke();
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

in my App portable class I have a static method that is calling after login complete: 
[image]

But in this scope I only can use Static method, I wish to call a non static method for re rendering the entire Page (with menus, etc..) after login. How can I do this?

Above my successLoginAction:

```
       public static Action SuccessfulLoginAction
    {
        get
        {
            return new Action(() =>
            {
                //var masterDetailPage = Application.Current.MainPage as MasterDetailPage;
                //masterDetailPage.Detail = new NavigationPage((Page)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Painel)));
                //masterDetailPage.IsPresented = false;
                _NavPage.Navigation.PopAsync();
                _NavPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new MainPage());
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: If your `FacebookLoginPage` is being displayed as a modal, couldn't you just have your `MainPage` displayed beneath it, so when you call `PopModalAsync()` your `MainPage()` would already be displayed? Also, your `SuccessfulLoginAction` should be returned an Action that is declared with async and await like: `return new Action(async () => { await _NavPage.Navigation.PopModalAsync(); ....});`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is don't make it static.
If you change it to just a public property, you can access it through `App.Current`.
To be more specific:

```
public Action SuccessfulLoginAction
{
    get
    {
        return new Action(() =>
        {
            //var masterDetailPage = Application.Current.MainPage as MasterDetailPage;
            //masterDetailPage.Detail = new NavigationPage((Page)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Painel)));
            //masterDetailPage.IsPresented = false;
            _NavPage.Navigation.PopAsync();
            _NavPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new MainPage());
        });
    }
}
```

Then call it from anywhere like this:

```
((App)Application.Current).SuccessfulLoginAction.Invoke();
```

That way you can access your `_NavPage` as the whole thing is bound to the instance of `App`.

Comment: ((App)Application.Current.SuccessfulLoginAction.Invoke()) not works, the error is: "Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1061 'Application' does not contain a definition for 'SuccessfulLoginAction' and no extension method 'SuccessfulLoginAction' accepting a first argument of type 'Application' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
"

Comment: @IgorMonteiro Whoops typo. See my edit.
`((App)Application.Current.SuccessfulLoginAction.Invoke())` fixed to:
`((App)Application.Current).SuccessfulLoginAction.Invoke();`

Comment: tks my friend.. pls like my question :)